# Where is the Gnome-Shell Shutdown options

Tags: 11.10, gnome, shutdown

My girlfriend is using Gnome-Shell (That traitor!! ^^) and she wants to know where is the options for Shutdown like in Unity (Another point for me and Unity hehe).

How can I add/find this option to help her.

**NOTE** - If the option is not available then thats life. What can we do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> the Suspend option becomes "Power Off".

Edit:  Although I should add that I use gnome-shell and I prefer to use an extension to add  the power off option to the menu without having to hold alt.  [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html) offers the "Alternative Status Menu" extension which adds Power Off and Hibernate options to the menu permanently.

Edit2: There is actually a site for gnome-shell extensions that provides some needed extensions.  The site is [located here](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and there is [an extension for an alternate menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5/alternative-status-menu/) that contains "Power Off" by default.  If you're running gnome-shell you can go there and just flip the switch from off to on and then confirm that you want to install the extension.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the extension in your edit. I will never understand why the GNOME devs opted to hide the shutdown option on a shell they were trying to design to be as easy to use as possible.

Comment: That would be because they dont have a life, and being so they never leave they computers, they assume that thats the case will all man kind and implement the shutdown option as a remote thing that will be rarely used...

Answer (score 0):

install
gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
using synaptic package maneger or using terminal working for gnome 12.04.

Comment: I cannot find any package called `gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu`. Are you sure that's what it's called?