# shutdown bar is not appearing anywhere

Tags: gnome, applet

i am using ubuntu 11.10 in GNOME interface and there is no shutdown bar/option appearing on desktop . I have also used some solutions just like:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu

but this is showing some error message in the terminal while typing last command.

Please provided me with best solutions

Comment: what was the error in terminal?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71283/where-is-the-gnome-shell-shutdown-options

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/14/shut-down-menu/
[image]

Or press ans hold <kbd>alt</kbd> key to show the shutdown option

Answer (score 1):

By default in Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 if you click on your username on right top corner and then press alt key then suspend option will change to shutdown and then you can shutdown or restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

shutdown option is on the top right corner. click the icon there and you will see a shutdown option. alternatively you could type the following in terminal:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

termianl can be opened by this shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: The option is not visible in gnome 3.6 or newer, but the terminal solution is good!